# React with Typescript - MUI Textfield - How to get TextFields value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

#### Question:

I'm new to javascript and typescript and ran into a problem with trying to refactor a simple tic-tac-toe program from vanilla css to MUI components.

The method that handles input for the `<input type='text'>` tag expects a HTMLInputElement but recieves a HTMLDivElement because MUI's `TextField` is a `div` contaning an `input`.

Heres the question how would I refactor this function to get the `input` tags value from the `TextField` MUI component?

#### Ideas:

I was thinking that I should expect a the `HTMLDivElement` then find it's child `input` tag, but how would I do this?

#### Current Implementation

```
<input
    type='text'
    value={players[0]}
    onInput={(e) => handleInput(e, 0)}
/>
```

#### Using MUI TextField Implementation

```
<TextField type='text' value={players[0]} onInput={(e) => handleInput(e, 0)} />
```

#### Method that handles the onInput event.

```
const handleInput = (event: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>, index: number) => {
    console.log("handleInput");
    const newPlayers = [...players]; //
    newPlayers.splice(index, 1, event.currentTarget.value); 
    setPlayers(newPlayers); // Set the state for the players
};
```

#### Here is what MUI's `TextField` component produces.

```
<div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root css-1u3bzj6-MuiFormControl-root-MuiTextField-root">
    <div class="MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-root MuiInputBase-colorPrimary MuiInputBase-formControl css-9ddj71-MuiInputBase-root-MuiOutlinedInput-root">
        <input aria-invalid="false" type="text" class="MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-input css-1t8l2tu-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input" value="" id="mui-2">
        <fieldset aria-hidden="true" class="MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline css-1d3z3hw-MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline">
            <legend class="css-nnbavb">
                <span class="notranslate">​</span>
            </legend>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found how to get access to the `input` element but I cannot find out how to get the tags value still. Using the HTML structure generated by the `TextField` component I have been able to dig out the input element by doing this `const elem = event.currentTarget.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].textContent;` but now that I have `elem` holding the `input` tag how can I get its value?

Comment: Just realized that the `TextField` component also is not updating the `input` tags value when I type. I found that I can extract the value by using `elem.nodeValue` but this returns `null` as `input`'s value is not updated when typing into the field.